# Node newbie - Nodejs function for post to AWS S3 is not returning Callback

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, callback, upload

I've created (basterised) some code which I can execute on its own and my file is uploaded to S3.

But, what I want to be able to do is to have a common Upload file that I can call upon from any other file and have the Location of the newly added file returned in the callback. I've spent hours on this now and I just can't work it out. I'm not a Dev but know enough to be destructive, any help would be much appreciated.

```
function uploadprofileimage(profile, callback) {
console.log('start uploading a new profile Image');

// call S3 to retrieve upload file to specified bucket
var uploadParams = {Bucket: BUCKET_NAME, Key: '', Body: ''};
var file = profile;

// Configure the file stream and obtain the upload parameters
var fileStream = fs.createReadStream(file);
fileStream.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('File Error', err);
});

uploadParams.Body = fileStream;
uploadParams.Key = path.basename(file);


// this works but I need it to call back
// call S3 to retrieve upload file to specified bucket
// s3.upload (uploadParams, function (err, res) {
//     if (err) {
//         console.log("Error", err);
//     }
//     console.log("Upload Success", res.Location);
// });

 s3.upload(uploadParams , function (err,response) {
    console.log('response Location: ' + response.Location);
         if (err) {
             console.log("Error", err);
         }
         console.log("Upload Success", response.Location);
         return callback(null, response.Location);
     });
   }exports.uploadprofileimage = uploadprofileimage;
```

Comment: What is the problem here?

Comment: Ok, well, I've had some help, and my isse was the calling function which had to many variables in it.

Comment: rather than `return callback(null, response.Location);` try `callback(null, response.Location);` we are not actually returning anything, we are calling the function that is passed as input parameter. if you do want to return the output of the callback function, we then need to use promises with async await!